# Shortest path in maze allowing to go through a limited number of walls?

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, shortest-path

Without the ability to go through walls, I figured it is a standard Dijkstra's problem. However, if I were given X times to bypass/go through walls, how can I model it to apply Dijkstra's algorithm?

Comment: That's tricky. For every vertex you need to store the shortest path for every allowed number of bypasses. That conflicts with the greedy nature of Dijkstra's.

Comment: What are the costs of moving through a wall and moving through a passage? Are they the same for all cells? Do they depend on how much times we already moved through a wall?

Comment: Moving through passage and through wall costs 1 (step) , same for all

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that your maze is represented as a graph:  Create X + 1 copies of the graph, and create a directed edge between level `i` and level `i + 1` for cells that are adjacent with a wall between them.  Finally merge all of the exits.

From a practical point of view, of course you do not need to create copies of the graph, just keep track of ordered pairs of (vertex, level).